# How to burn Ubuntu to disc for a pc that has no operating system?

Tags: laptop, hp, system

How do you burn Ubuntu to a cd 700MB for a laptop that has no operating system?

Comment: Do you have a working computer to make the disc in the first place?

Comment: you need to switch on to any PC before moving to your new laptop so as to create a bootable cd or pen drive. you can find more details here http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Answer (score 1):

i guess you only used ubuntu with the windows installer or something similar before.

A ubuntu (or any other distro) can boot up a system on it's own. no need for an OS there at all. In fact, even if there was an OS installed, it would be irrelevant to starting the ubuntu install.

Just burn the CD, and configure your BIOS to boot from it. if it's a newer computer, UEFI may give you trouble, but read on and you will be fine.

Comment: can you give step or video pls

Comment: @user139057 update your question (click Edit up there) and add all the computers you have available and the computer you are trying to install to. the more information the better. someone will probably came up with a recipe for you. but try to be specific

Answer (score 0):

It is possible (if you do not have another PC to burn the CD, don't want to learn how to, or just don't want to) to buy Ubuntu 12.10 32-bit Desktop. It costs £4.71 and can be found [here](http://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?products_id=1027).

Answer (score 0):

You can't easily use a CD, which normally only hold 600MB.

You can't create a DVD or USB boot disk, with no application or OS on the machine.

---

You **can** create a boot DVD using Mac, Windows, or a friend's Linux PC (the preferred method).

Best option: *Get a friend to create a boot USB drive, on the current release of Ubuntu.*

Fall-back option: *Use DVD burning software (on Windows/Mac) with downloaded .ISO file [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).*

Cheat method (may work): *Purchase magazine with attached bootable USB or DVD of your preferred Ubuntu version.*